# C# Read Json And Read Data

Tags: c#, json, roblox

I Want Make C# App That Shows Your Roblox Name By UserID

Here Is My Profile's Json But I Dont Know How To Get Json Data: https://api.roblox.com/users/157816362

For Example:

```
json = new System.Net.WebClient(){ Proxy = null }.DownloadString("https://api.roblox.com/users/157816362");
label1.text = json.Username
```

Something Like This.

Can You Guys/Girls Please Help Me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres an example program, you have to create a web request, pass the url you want in and then get the response from that.

From there you have to 'deserialize' the response into an object that you can use in code. I used the System.Json one, but there are others like newtonsoft that you can choose from.

```
internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://api.roblox.com/users/157816362");
        var response = webRequest.GetResponse();
        var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        if (responseStream != null)
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            string body = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var robloxProfile = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<RobloxResponse>(body);
        }
    }
}

public class RobloxResponse
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string AvatarUri { get; set; }
    public bool AvatarFinal { get; set; }
    public bool IsOnline { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: so how can i change label1's text to username?

Comment: Using Corys code it would be  label1.Text = robloxProfile.Username;

Comment: i got error like this: https://i.ibb.co/9cV3P18/igoterror.png

how can i fix it?

Comment: Youll need these references at the top:
using System.IO;

using System.Net;

using System.Text.Json;

Comment: i cant access robloxProfile.Username from Button1_Click How Can I Fix This?

Answer (score 1):

You almost have the answer. You should create a class that maps to the json, download the [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) nuget and convert the string data that you get from the WebClient.DownloadString into a class through the JsonConvert class. Like this:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        using (var client = new WebClient()) {
            var data = client.DownloadString("https://api.roblox.com/users/157816362");
            var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonData>(data);
            Console.WriteLine($"{jsonData.Username}");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class JsonData {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }
}
```